# deveoping Entity class using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Hi i am developing a persistence layer for one object user using (JPA) and I am writing code in a editor and not using spring hibernate anything i have written the below code but its showing package javax.persistence .*; not found how do i make this to work can any one help.

this is the class i have written.

```
//import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

@Entity(name = "USER") //Name of the entity

public class User implements Serializable
{
    private int userId;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String roles;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)    
    public int getUserId()
    {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int UserId) 
    {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false)
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(int userName) 
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(int password) 
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(int firstName) 
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false)
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(int lastName) 
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "ROLES", nullable = false)
    public String getRoles()
    {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(int roles) 
    {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User() 
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: In case you haven't already knew, latest Hibernate versions implements JPA specification (they're not enitrely exclusive to each other). Other popular implementation of JPA are eclipselink & toplink.

Answer (score 2):

add [persistence api](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/persistence/persistence-api/1.0b/persistence-api-1.0b.jar) to your build path

Comment: I have to download those,can u give me a link from where i can download it

Comment: k thank you where i have to put that jar file in the folder where i have written java file there.

Comment: are you using some IDe?

Comment: no, i writing in editor in linux OS,i have created one folder inside that i have created my java file..

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html see this and add this jar to classpath while compiling and running, if you were using IDE it would not be a pain to maintain by hand

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the persistence.jar in your classpath.

Comment: I have to download those,can u give me a link from where i can download it

Comment: k thank you where i have to put that jar file in the folder where i have written java file there.